# how to set unequal x axis intervals in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Now I just simply use `plt.plot(x,y1,'b.-')` to plot a figure, but it turns out so many data are displayed between 0 to 10 on the x axis, so I want to set x axis like this `0,1,5,10,100,1000,100000`

thus, the massive data between 0 to 10 can be more spread out.

How can I do it in Python, I am using Matplotlib

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*0,1,5,10,100,1000,100000?*

If you can live with (0.01, 0.1,), 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000,… - then change the xscale to log:

```
plt.xscale('log')
```

Answer (score 2):

See the accepted answer to the question [How do I convert (or scale) axis values and redefine the tick frequency in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143848/how-do-i-convert-or-scale-axis-values-and-redefine-the-tick-frequency-in-matpl) Essentially, the [`matplotlib.pyplot.xticks`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks) command can be used to control to location and labels of the tick marks.

However, your data will still be plotted on a linear scale, so this won't strecth out the data between 0 and 10. You will need to use a different axis scaling to do this, using, for example, [`set_xscale`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xscale).