# Overlapping y-axis tick label and x-axis tick label in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

If I create a plot with matplotlib using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
xx = np.arange(0,5, .5)
yy = np.random.random( len(xx) )
plt.plot(xx,yy)
plt.imshow()
```

I get a result that looks like the attached image.  The problem is the
bottom-most y-tick label overlaps the left-most x-tick label.  This
looks unprofessional.  I was wondering if there was an automatic
way to delete the bottom-most y-tick label, so I don't have
the overlap problem.  The fewer lines of code, the better.
[image]

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In the ticker module there is a class called [MaxNLocator](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MaxNLocator) that can take a `prune` kwarg.
Using that you can remove the first tick:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
import numpy as np
xx = np.arange(0,5, .5)
yy = np.random.random( len(xx) )
plt.plot(xx,yy)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(prune='lower'))
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 23):

You can pad the ticks on the x-axis:

```
ax.tick_params(axis='x', pad=15)
```

Replace `ax` with `plt.gca()` if you haven't stored the variable `ax` for the current figure.

You can also pad both the axes removing the `axis` parameter.

Comment: Seems very elegant, but unfortunately doesn't seem to work on 3D plots, such as `plot_surface`.

Answer (score 7):

A very elegant way to fix the overlapping problem is increasing the padding of the x- and y-tick labels (i.e. the distance to the axis). Leaving out the corner most label might not always be wanted. In my opinion, in general it looks nice if the labels are a little bit farther from the axis than given by the default configuration.

The padding can be changed via the matplotlibrc file or in your plot script by using the commands

```
import matplotlib as mpl

mpl.rcParams['xtick.major.pad'] = 8
mpl.rcParams['ytick.major.pad'] = 8
```

Most times, a padding of 6 is also sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

This is answered in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143848/how-do-i-convert-or-scale-axis-values-and-redefine-the-tick-frequency-in-matpl). Basically, you use something like this:

```
plt.xticks([list of tick locations], [list of tick lables])
```