# How do I change the scale of imshow in matplotlib without stretching the image?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wanted to plot using imshow in a manner similar to the second example here http://www.scipy.org/Plotting_Tutorial but to redefine the scale for the axis. I'd also like the image to stay still while I do this!

The code from the example:

```
from scipy import *
from pylab import *

# Creating the grid of coordinates x,y 
x,y = ogrid[-1.:1.:.01, -1.:1.:.01]

z = 3*y*(3*x**2-y**2)/4 + .5*cos(6*pi * sqrt(x**2 +y**2) + arctan2(x,y))

hold(True)
# Creating image
imshow(z, origin='lower', extent=[-1,1,-1,1])

xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
title('A spiral !')

# Adding a line plot slicing the z matrix just for fun. 
plot(x[:], z[50, :])

show()
```

If I modify the extent to be wider, eg:

```
imshow(z, origin='lower', extent=[-4,4,-1,1])
```

Then the resulting image is stretched. But all I wanted to do was change the ticks to coincide with my data. I know I can use pcolor to conserve the X and Y data, though that has other ramifications to it.

I found this answer which allows me to manually redo all the ticks:

[How do I convert (or scale) axis values and redefine the tick frequency in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143848/how-do-i-convert-or-scale-axis-values-and-redefine-the-tick-frequency-in-matpl)

But that seems a bit overkill.

Is there a way to only change the extent shown by the labels?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `help(imshow)` will find the `aspect` argument, which after a bit of experimentation seems to give what you want (a square image of the spiral but with x scale from -4 to 4 and y from -1 to 1) when used like this:

```
imshow(z, origin='lower', extent=[-4,4,-1,1], aspect=4)
```

But now your `plot` is still from -1 to 1, so you'd have to modify that as well...

```
plot(x[:]*4, z[50, :])
```

I think when you have several elements that would have to be modified, just using a one-line tick relabeling instead isn't overkill:

```
xticks(xticks()[0], [str(t*4) for t in xticks()[0]])
```

Comment: Aspect is a good solution for my use case as I don't have a plot there. And you fix the xticks in a more elegant solution than mine. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against using the `aspect` keyword for this task, unlike the accepted answer. Let the image dictate the aspect ratio of your Axes, and simply multiply the `extent` of the image by a scaling factor. If you don't do that, you will be forced to scale all the subsequent artists you add.

The code snippet below shows the image with the default behavior: assigning 1 data unit to 1 pixel.

```
image:np.ndarray = ... # We will assume that you already loaded an image.

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.show()
ax.imshow(image, cmap="gray", origin="lower")
ax.autoscale(False)
fig.canvas.draw()
```

This snippet scales the image.

```
SCALE = 5e-6/105

image:np.ndarray = ... # We will assume that you already loaded an image.

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.show()
image_artist = ax.imshow(image, cmap="gray", origin="lower")
image_artist.set_extent(np.array(image_artist.get_extent())*SCALE)
ax.autoscale(False)
fig.canvas.draw()
```

[image]